# Cannot access disposed socket

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

I have an async socket application that I'm trying to setup to handle exceptions better. When a socket exception is caught, I shutdown the socket and take them back to the "Connection" screen where it tries to reconnect the socket. Problem is - when trying to reconnect I get an error that the current socket is disposed.

When I try to reconnect, is there a way to check if the socket was disposed, and if so re-instantiate the socket?

```
 catch (Exception e)
 {
                ShutDownAfterException();

                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("From ReceiveCallback");
 }

private void ShutDownAfterException()
{
            Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            Client.Close();
            Client = null;

            Stop();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(() => Messenger.Default.Send<NavigateMessage>(new NavigateMessage(ConnectViewModel.ViewName, this))));
}
```

Comment: The socket is always going to be disposed at the moment you reconnect, since your code is disposing it first. Given that, just reinstantiate the socket without checking if it was disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Socket.Close` method will actually disconnect *and* dispose the socket meaning that when you next  access the socket instance an exception will be thrown.

If you intend disconnect the socket only use  `Socket.Disconnect(reuseSocket: true)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I'm intending to do